# Disadvantages of using properties only with no corresponding fields in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have classes which have automatic properties only like public customerName {get; set;}. They are public because they are accessed outside the class. They can also be accessed inside the class. They offer good encapsulation and better debugging. I can put a breakpoint on one if I need to know who is accessing it and when.

My question is what are the disadvantages of using properties only with no corresponding fields? I can make the setter or getter private, internal.. etc which means I also have flexibility of scoping it when needed.

Comment: +1 anything that reveals an edge case or specific issues with something is a good question to me. (re: Marc's BinaryFormatter complication)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Serialization with `BinaryFormatter` - you have **big** problems if you need to change your property to a "regular" property later, for example to add some validation / eventing /etc - sinc `BinaryFormatter` uses the field names. And you can't duplicate this, since the field name the compiler generates cannot be written as legal C#.

Which is a good reason to look at a contract-based serializer instead. See [this blog entry](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html) for more info.

Comment: It's nasty, and not something to be considered at all but - could you hack yourself out by checking the automatic field name in Reflector?

Comment: That won't help much - the field name *cannot* be written in C# (intentionally) - so you'd have to implement `ISerializable` or a serialization surrogate; lots of work just because you wanted to add validation to a property. But to stress: my answer here is "don't use BinaryFormatter" - and keep using auto-props ;-p

Answer (score 6):

You can't create **truly read only** property, because you have to define both setter and getter. You can only use private setter to achieve pseudo-readonly property from outside.

Otherwise, as said above there are no other disadvantages.

Comment: I'm only adding this comment because this is no longer true. `public int X => 3` is treated as a property with no `set` accessor, even internally to the containing object.

Answer (score 3):

There are no disadvantages for simple properties. The compiler creates the backing field for you. This [blog entry](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/03/03/c-3-0-automatic-properties-explained.aspx) explains how the compiler treats automatically implemented properties.

Answer (score 3):

Not really a disadvantage, but you have to be aware of the default values of automatic properties. With "classic" properties we always used to initialize the backing fields, e.g. like this:

```
private bool _flag = true;
public bool Flag
{
  get { return _flag; }
  set { _flag = value; }
}
```

This made it obvious what the default value of the property is.

With automatic properties, you have to know what the default values are for the different types (e.g. false for bool). If you don't want the property to have the default value you have to initialize it in the constructor:

```
class MyClass
{
  public bool Flag { get; set; }
  public MyClass()
  {
    Flag = true;
  }
}
```

This means, you **have to implement a constructor** if you want to initialize your properties to non default values or if a property is of a reference type (class).

But as I wrote, I do not really think of this as a disadvantage, just something you have to know.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, there *is* a corresponding field.  You just don't see it because the compiler creates it for you.  Automatic properties are just syntactic sugar or shorthand way to create the field.

Answer (score 1):

No major things. Just edge cases like where you need to pass a property to a method where the parameter is passed by reference (`ref` or `out`) which isn't possible with a property (because internally, they're just get_Property/set_Property methods implemented by the compiler, not special fields of some kind) and you would need an explicit private backing field for this.

EDIT: Oh, and seconding the 'no `readonly`' properties, which is actually fairly common.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to perform any specific logic in the get and/or set accessors, there's no disadvantage...

Answer (score 0):

I say that they are bad from a code readability standpoint.  Syntax sugar is nice for writing code but horrible for reading code.  As developers the code we leave behind will ultimately be inherited by some poor developer that will have to make sense out of what we did and what is going on in the code.  I really am against changing a language to simply save keystrokes when there is an established syntax for the same constructs.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it makes it less readable. You do have one field less to read, and the code is saying "this is a simplest possible property, it's here just to allow encapsulation if I need it some day".

Comment: Why is it less readable? Are you referring to the automatic property part of the fact there's no field defined? Either way, any good developer what the property is used for?